# HTML PRINT table breaks when increasing the height of Thead or Tfoot

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a print table with Thead and Tfoot print in every page. for some reason when i increase the height of the Thead or Tfoot aleast 250px or more, the print breaks.

This is the printpreview if `thead` or `tfoot` height is 200px and below

[image: 200px and Below]

This is the printpreview if the `thead` or `tfoot` height is 300px and above
[image: 300px]

It breaks the table when increasing the height of either thead or tfoot.
Does anyone know a fix for this issue. i want to increase the height of my thead and tfoot.

```css
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  margin-top: 0.5cm;
}
   @media print{
    table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
     
    }
}

table,thead,tbody, td, th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
table, tfoot td{
    bottom: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
 
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            
            <th colspan='6' style="height: 200px;">
                <button id='print' onclick='window.print()'>print</button>
                HEADER SPACE
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='10%' >&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='20%' ></td>
            <td width='40%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
            <td width='10%' ></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan='6' style="height: 200px;">FOOTER SPACE</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<!-- <p style="position:fixed;bottom:0;">For Property Office Use</p> -->


       </body>
       </html>
```